# Texture painting on backface

Tags: texture-painting

I'm new to Blender, I have modeled a naga and I'm painting a texture and some parts are unpaintable from the out of my model.

Them parts are "back faces", how can I enable painting on them from both sides ?

Edit : Here's the exact symptoms, I cannot draw on the part at right, the undrawable part disappear when checking the "Backface culling".

[image: Problem screen cast]

Black lines of the *undrawable* part have been made from the inner of the head.

Comment: Hello, could you please give some screenshots and more details so we can see what is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**14-11-2022 edit**: The real problem there is that I was inexperienced and my model had bad normal because I made a weird sandwich of objects.

**Original answer**

> Often I find that view camera affects my painting as well. – Craig D Jones

It's my problem, I have disabled the "Norm" option [image: Item to unckeck] and now I can paint everywhere. This option is located in the *left panel of 3D View in texture paint mode (show with <kbd>T</kbd>)* > *Option tab* > *Paint by projection* > *Normal*

Uncheck it and  nowyou can paint on faces at 180° of the view...

[image: Global view]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Blender 2.93.9 and face the same problem. To fix it was necessary turn off the "Backface Culling" option.

*"Texture paint" workspace > "Active Active tool" tab > Options > Backface Culling*